# NullPointerException when implementing Java interface from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, interface, nullpointerexception, rx-java2

I'm trying to implement `BiFunction` interface from RxJava in Kotlin and I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

This is the Java interface that I'm implementing in Kotlin. It's from RxJava 2.

```
package io.reactivex.functions;

import io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull;

/**
 * A functional interface (callback) that computes a value based on multiple input values.
 * @param <T1> the first value type
 * @param <T2> the second value type
 * @param <R> the result type
 */
public interface BiFunction<T1, T2, R> {

    /**
     * Calculate a value based on the input values.
     * @param t1 the first value
     * @param t2 the second value
     * @return the result value
     * @throws Exception on error
     */
    @NonNull
    R apply(@NonNull T1 t1, @NonNull T2 t2) throws Exception;
}
```

This is my implementation

```
class MonitoringStateReducer: BiFunction<MonitoringViewState, MonitoringResult, 
    MonitoringViewState> {
    override fun apply(
        previousState: MonitoringViewState,
        result: MonitoringResult
    ): MonitoringViewState {
        when (result) {
           //Returns a non-null new state
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in the ViewModel, I try to use it, but it throws a NullPointerException.

> 2019-08-22 09:57:41.049 6925-6925/com.name.app E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.name.app, PID: 6925
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.name.app/com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: accumulator is null
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2907)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1641)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: accumulator is null
>           at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
>           at io.reactivex.Observable.scanWith(Observable.java:11537)
>           at io.reactivex.Observable.scan(Observable.java:11502)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringViewModel.compose(MonitoringViewModel.kt:47)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringViewModel.(MonitoringViewModel.kt:18)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringViewModel_Factory.get(MonitoringViewModel_Factory.java:25)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringViewModel_Factory.get(MonitoringViewModel_Factory.java:8)
>           at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
>           at com.name.app.di.viewmodel.ViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelFactory.kt:12)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(MonitoringActivity.kt:46)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(MonitoringActivity.kt:26)
>           at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringActivity.getViewModel(Unknown
>   Source:7)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringActivity.bind(MonitoringActivity.kt:85)
>           at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringActivity.onCreate(MonitoringActivity.kt:119)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2860)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1641) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)

```
class MonitoringViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val processor: MonitoringProcessor
) : BaseViewModel<MonitoringIntention, MonitoringViewState>() {
    //Properties that are not relevant for the question

    private val reducer: MonitoringStateReducer = MonitoringStateReducer()

    private fun compose(): Observable<MonitoringViewState> {
        return intentsSubject.compose(intentFilter)
            .map(actionFromIntent)
            .compose(processor)
            .scan(MonitoringViewState.init(), reducer) //Exception is here
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .replay(1)
            .autoConnect(0)
    }

    override fun state(): Observable<MonitoringViewState> = compose()

    //Functions that are not relevant for the question
}
```

This code doesn´t work either.

```
private val reducer by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    MonitoringStateReducer()
}
```

However, if I replace the reducer with this code, it works.

```
private val reducer: BiFunction<MonitoringViewState, MonitoringResult, MonitoringViewState>
    get() = MonitoringStateReducer()
```

Tested on Kotlin 1.3.40 and 1.3.50.

Comment: check the stack trace, it could be that `state()` is called and subscribed to somewhere from parent constructor.

Comment: Post the full `MonitoringStateReducer.apply` method. If it's too long, then post at least a few branches of the `when` block. The problem likely has to do with something in there.

Answer (score 11):

The problem comes from the Kotlin class initialization order. The crash is due to the fact that `BaseViewModel` constructor is calling the `state()` method that is overridden in the child `MonitoringViewModel` class. As a result, when the `reducer` is accessed, it hasn't  initialized yet. During construction of a new instance of a derived class, the base class initialization is done as the first step and it happens before the initialization logic of the derived class is run. Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546), which describes a pretty similar problem. [Derived class initialization order](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order) Kotlin's documentation section should be useful too.

Comment: Related: [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Answer (score 4):

**@Valeriy Katkov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635447/1401164) is correct, please accept his answer.**

Here is a code simulating the same scenario:

```
fun main() {
    MonitoringViewModel()
}

open abstract class BaseViewModel {

    init {
        state()
    }

    abstract fun state()
}

class MonitoringViewModel: BaseViewModel() {

    private val reducer1: MonitoringStateReducer = MonitoringStateReducer()
    private val reducer2: BiFunction<MonitoringViewState, MonitoringResult, MonitoringViewState>
        get() = MonitoringStateReducer()

    override fun state() {
        Observable.just(MonitoringResult(3))
                .scan(MonitoringViewState(0), reducer1)
                .subscribe { state -> println(state.value) }
    }

}

data class MonitoringViewState(val value: Int)

data class MonitoringResult(val value: Int)

class MonitoringStateReducer : BiFunction<MonitoringViewState, MonitoringResult,
        MonitoringViewState> {
    override fun apply(
            previousState: MonitoringViewState,
            result: MonitoringResult
    ): MonitoringViewState {
        return MonitoringViewState(previousState.value + result.value)
    }
}
```

If you run this code with the `scan` operator using `reducer1` you will see the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: accumulator is null

If you run the code with `scan` operator using `reducer2`, it succeeds.

#### Why does it crash when using `reduce1`?

From @Valeriy Katkov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635447/1401164):

> The crash is due to the fact that BaseViewModel constructor is calling the state() method that is overridden in the child MonitoringViewModel class. As a result, when the reducer is accessed, it hasn't initialized yet. During construction of a new instance of a derived class, the base class initialization is done as the first step and it happens before the initialization logic of the derived class is run.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this part of the stacktrace holds the answer:

> ```
> at com.name.app.features.monitoring.presentation.MonitoringViewModel_Factory.get(MonitoringViewModel_Factory.java:8)
> at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
> at com.name.app.di.viewmodel.ViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelFactory.kt:12)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
> ```

What I'm taking from this is that you're using Dagger to create instances of your `MonitoringViewModel` class. I'm not *sure* that Dagger does what I'm about to describe, but I know other libraries (like Gson) do, and it fits the pattern...

It is possible to create instances of objects without actually invoking constructors if you use the `Unsafe` class. See the "Avoid Initialization" section of this article: http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

If that's happening here, then your `private val reducer = MonitoringStateReducer()` won't ever actually be executed, because that's part of the class initialization. Therefore, `reducer` is never initialized and is `null` when you try to use it in `compose()`.

I'm not sure why that would make it not work when using the `by lazy` delegate, but it does make sense for why it works when you provide a custom `get()`: it is no longer part of class initialization, and is instead evaluated on demand.

Try creating instances of this class without using Dagger and see if your "normal" initialization works.

Comment: Was curious how you went about this. Sounds like a very good possibility. I naively searched dagger's repo for Unsafe and found no mentions to it. The reason I ask is also because being a framework that generates the code at compile tine and requires all the info about classes, if find it strange that they would require unsafe.

Comment: Maybe it isn't explicitly `Unsafe`, and there's some other way (that I'm not aware of) to create instances without normal initialization. As for how I went about it, really it was just that I had read that blog post somewhat recently so the idea of creating instances without initialization was fresh in my mind.

Comment: I highly doubt that this is a Dagger issue. They don't use `Unsafe` anywhere in their repository nor in the generated code. Similarly, ViewModel doesn't `Unsafe`. I think this might be a Kotlin issue, but I don't know too much about the internals of Kotlin.

Comment: Upvoting as this is a good answer, but for the scenario of this question, the problem is correctly described by @Valeriy Katkov